# python context sensitive regex for parsing hierchical text structure

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this:

```
Group 1:
Line A
Line B
Line C
Group 2:
Line A
Line B
```

I am wondering if it is possible to parse this with a regex with the results being something like:

```
Group: 1, Line: A
Group: 1, Line: B
Group: 1, Line: C
Group: 2, Line: A
Group: 2, Line: B
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
regex = r'''(?x)
(?<=Group\s(\d):\n)
(?:Line\s\w+\n)*
Line\s(\w+)
'''
match_iter = re.finditer(regex,test,re.M|re.S|re.I)
for m in match_iter:
    print m.groups()
```

But this is wrong because I am only getting:

```
('1', 'C')
('2', 'B')
```

And I'm stuck here... any idea how I can do this? (or if it is even possible to do with re)

EDIT:
I am looking for a regex only solution because I am trying to plug this into a light framework that will only take a regex and not arbitrary code. I can't use anything with states etc. This means In the above code snippet I can only change the value of 'regex'.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = re.compile("(Group) (\d+)|(Line) (\w+)")

INPUT = """
Group 1:
Line A
Line B
Line C
Group 2:
Line A
Line B"""

def main():
    group, line = None, None
    for match in regex.finditer(INPUT):
        if match.group(1):
            # found a Group
            group = match.group(2)
        else:
            # found a Line
            line = match.group(4)
            print("Group: {group}, Line: {line}".format(group=group, line=line))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

returns

```
Group: 1, Line: A
Group: 1, Line: B
Group: 1, Line: C
Group: 2, Line: A
Group: 2, Line: B
```

Comment: Any way to do this without states? It needs to be a regex only because I am trying to plug this into a light 'framework' that would only take regex not arbitrary code

Comment: @jeff: I don't believe it's possible with a single regex; what framework are you using? Maybe we can suggest another approach?

Comment: We have our own framework which we use to modify outputs of certain commands. For example, in the above string, I can enter something like (1,B) as a key and then change the value of that line or some number of items in the line to arbitrary values.

Answer (score 0):

This has provided me with quite a lot of entertainment this evening. The constraint of only varying your regex is very interesting. The closest I can come to giving you what you want is two options.

```
txt = 'Group 1:\nLine A\nLine B\nLine C\nGroup 2:\nLine A\nLine B'

re.findall(r'''(?:Group )(\d).*?(?:\nLine )?([A-Z]+)(?:\nLine )?([A-Z]+)(?:\nLine )?([A-Z]+)?''', txt, re.S)

regex = r'''(?:Group )(\d)
             .*?
            (?:\nLine )?([A-Z]+)  # Must Match 
            (?:\nLine )?([A-Z]+)  # Must Match
            (?:\nLine )?([A-Z]+)? # The matching group made optional by the ?
         '''
re.findall(regex, txt, re.S|re.X)
```

Returns:

```
[('1', 'A', 'B', 'C'), 
 ('2', 'A', 'B', '')]
```

The second option is a variation on Hugh's suggestion, but I make the Group and Line non-capturing with the `(?:...)`:

```
re.findall(r'''(?:Group )(\d)+|(?:Line )([A-Z]+)''', txt, re.S)
```

Returns:

```
[('1', ''), 
 ('', 'A'),
 ('', 'B'), 
 ('', 'C'), 
 ('2', ''), 
 ('', 'A'), 
 ('', 'B')]
```

Since you don't seem to be able to do anything interesting with the data, it hardly makes sense for me to manipulate it further. I think I like the latter solution better, because it is more easily extensible to variations on your data, and the former is not as scalable. (How many optionally matching groups are you going to paste into your regex?)